# iPhone Simulator Intermittent Slowdown

Tags: iphone, performance, simulator

Almost every time I use the iPhone Simulator, I get intermittent slowdowns. Everything is running smooth and then the whole UI randomly drops down to 1-5fps. View pushes, animations and everything related to the UI just becomes sluggish for 2-10 seconds. Then all of sudden it comes back to normal again.

I've googled this issue several times and just can't find a solution. My guess is that there's some 3rd party extension/plugin that's causing this slowdown, but I'm not sure how to debug this.

This has been the case for the last 4 SDK installations. Happens on all simulators (iPhone, iPhone 4 and iPad). Happens in my own apps as well as in Apple's stock apps (Photos, Safari, Settings) and even in the Home Screen.

This issue makes debugging/testing extremely annoying. Any guess what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a while, but it seems like Xcode 4.2 fixed this for good.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up deleting everything in the `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` folder. It had some really old folders back from the 3.0 days. Maybe some incompatibility, I'm not sure.

Haven't had the issue since.

**EDIT**: Nope, this is only a temporary fix. Still looking for a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some slowdowns in the simulator when FaceTime for Mac is running, but it's not as bad as you describe. Have you tried when nothing else is running on your Mac?

Comment: Ended up trying this. Only had XCode and Simulator running, but no luck. I'm still getting the slowdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Total long shot: Are you using Core Location at all? (GPS Stuff)?

I have seen the same kind of behavior your are talking about when I turn location tracking on inside my simulated iPhone app.

Comment: That could be it, but it doesn't explain the home screen getting affected by this.

Comment: I'm experiencing same problems. I don't use core location in any of my apps.